# Getting map corner coordinates with google maps - javascript api

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, coordinates

I am trying to get the four corners of the google map that an API asks for.

`swLat
 swLng
 neLat
 neLng`

I have the following code but these are returning objects and im not sure if this is what its even asking for. Would these pair up(once they return correctyl) NE --> ? Thanks

```
   var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions); 


        google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'bounds_changed', function() {
            var rectangle = new google.maps.Rectangle({
               bounds: map.getBounds()
            })
            var bounds = rectangle.getBounds();
            var NE = bounds.getNorthEast();
                var NEmark = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: NE,
            title: "NE"
          });
          var SW = bounds.getSouthWest();
          var SWmark = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: SW,
            title: "SW"
          });
          // North West
          var NW = new google.maps.LatLng(NE.lat(), SW.lng());
          var NWmark = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: NW,
            title: "NW"
          });
          // South East
          var SE = new google.maps.LatLng(SW.lat(), NE.lng());
          var SEmark = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: SE,
            title: "SE"
          });

          $scope.NE = NE
          $scope.NW = NW
          $scope.SW = SW
          $scope.SE = SE


          var polygon = new google.maps.Polygon({
            map: map,
            paths: [
              [NE, NW, SW, SE]
            ]
          });
          map.setZoom(map.getZoom() - 1);
        });
        console.log("SE" + $scope.SE) //all undefined
        console.log("NW" + $scope.NW)
        console.log("SW" + $scope.SW)
        console.log("NE" + $scope.NE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'bounds_changed', function() {
        var swLat = map.getBounds().getSouthWest().lat();
        var swLng = map.getBounds().getSouthWest().lng();
        var neLat = map.getBounds().getNorthEast().lat();
        var neLng = map.getBounds().getNorthEast().lng();       
        console.log('swLat: ' + swLat);
        console.log('swLng: ' + swLng);
        console.log('neLat: ' + neLat);
        console.log('neLng: ' + neLng);
    });
```

Hope this helps!